# IIS / Helicon ISAPI Rewrite Hotlinking Protection

Tags: iis, isapi-rewrite

I am using a shared hosting package with ISAPI Rewrite 3 installed.  The problem is that when I try to amend the .htaccess to prevent hotlinking, it doesn't work.  Does anyone have experience of ISAPI Rewrite that can shed light on what I'm doing wrong.  I put the file is put into the same directory as Default.aspx.  The .htaccess is :-

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Is the syntax right or something else is the case?  As always, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try creating a simple rule to ensure the .htaccess file rules are being processed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "RewriteBase /", but everything else looks good. It could be smth in your permissions.